# Related elements of related element

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following problem. When debugging a project where I'm playing around a bit with Code First, the Items are somehow not added to the purchase. The purchases are added to the client.

This is how I seed the Data.

```
public class PublicDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PublicDataContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(PublicDataContext context)
    {
        context.Clients.Add(new Client()
        {
            // ...
            Purchases = new[]
                       {
                           new Purchase()
                           {
                               // ...
                               Items = new[]
                                        {
                                            new Item()
                                            {
                                                // ...
                                            },
                                            new Item()
                                            {
                                                // ...
                                            }
                                        }
                           },
                           new Purchase()
                           {
                               // ...
                           }
                       }
        });
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

And this is how I declare the two ICollection properties:

```
public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Item> Items{ get; set; }
```

I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Is `Slides` = `Items`, a typo?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry I really should pay more attention when copy pasting stuff.. I edited my question

Comment: Do you mean with "*the Items are somehow not added to the purchase*" that the `Items` table in the database is empty after `Seed` or that the items *are* in the table but do not have the correct foreign key to the purchase?

Comment: This is actually a very good question :-). As I am just getting started with code first, I can't seem to find the Database using SQL Server Management Studio. In the web.config, I specified the following connection string: `<add name="PublicDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Public;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Try to remove that "*User Instance*" stuff, it is terrible and very confusing and follow the advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11548688/270591

Comment: Yeah, it was the "User Instance". Works fine now, but that was very strange... Want to write the last comment in an answer? I'll tick it then.

Comment: That wasn't really an answer to your question :) Maybe write it as your own answer that the problem was somewhere else (you can accept your own answer) with a link to marc_s' answer (and don't forget to give *him* an upvote if you haven't already, that is the *really* helpful answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly call `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

```
// add client stuff
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Oops, seems my copy pastry has failed, in the end there I call base.Seed(context), which should then save the changes on the context. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Slauma I found a solution. As mentioned in this post: [stackoverflow.com/a/11548688/270591](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11548688/270591). While I am still not fully clear on the why, the how of the solution is the following:

Remove `user instance = true` from the connection string.

I guess this has something to do with access rights and / or permissions.